# Item not added to list with classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have these two classes:

```
public class SpawnStringClass{
    public List<PlayerSpawn> playerSpawn;
}

public class PlayerSpawn
{
    public string PlayerName;
    public float posx;
    public float posz;
}
```

I created a variable Referencing to the first class:

```
SpawnStringClass SpawnClass = new SpawnStringClass(){playerSpawn = new List<PlayerSpawn>()};
                var item = new PlayerSpawn
                {
                    PlayerName = player.NickName.ToString(),
                    posx = SpawnX,
                    posz = SpawnZ
                };


                SpawnClass.playerSpawn.Add(item);
```

Now when I try to convert the Spawn string class with the list to json it doesn'T work.

```
SpawnString = JsonUtility.ToJson(SpawnClass);
Debug.Log(SpawnString);
```

Does anyone know why?

The classes are outside of the main mono behaviour class and the variable player.nickname, SpawnX and SpawnZ are declared.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current question doesn't demonstrate the issue you're talking about.

Comment: This is all i can provide why shouldn't this be reproducible? There are classes declaration of the class and adding an list element to the class.

Comment: How is it reproducible? [I've tried](https://rextester.com/OVDW42968)

Comment: Your code looks correct. Please provide the method how you tried to verify the behavior. It seems like your verification is wrong and thus not reproducible with your given examples.

Comment: @Llama I don't understand why this works in ur code. I will retry with logging the item elements

Comment: @S.JohnFagone You mean the debug.logs?

Comment: @Juju666 that is what's meant by a minimal reproducible example. You need to provide the exact code that would generate the exact same error if someone were to run it in a new and unrelated IDE or environment. If the sample code you provided does not reproduce the error, then it's not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Okay i found the issue. That in another statement when I try to convert to an array. My question is why it don't convert to an array using ToArray() and why it isn'T serializing to json?

Comment: Can you clarify "it doesn't work"? Does it throw an exception? Result in an empty string? What?

Comment: @Llama It throws nothing and just goes straight forward

Comment: So how do you know it's not working? That's what you need to tell us, since it's not clear what is wrong here.

Comment: @Llama It's not working. Else it should output some json

Comment: Is that because the resulting string is empty, or because of a bug in your display method?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html) say: _" the object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the Serializable attribute applied. The types of fields that you want to be included must be supported by the serializer; unsupported fields will be ignored, as will private fields, static fields, and fields with the NonSerialized attribute applied."_ I'm not familiar with this but perhaps try adding the `[Serializable]` attribute?

Comment: @Llama Will try

Comment: @Llama Thx that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `JsonUtility` uses the also built-in Unity serializer.

Refer to [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) and in particular the section **How to ensure a custom class can be serialized** where you can find

> Ensure it:
>
> - **Has the `[Serializable]` attribute**
> - Is not abstract
> - Is not static
> - Is not generic, though it may inherit from a generic class

Solution: Your both classes have to be attributed [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute)

```
[Serializable]
public class SpawnStringClass
{
    public List<PlayerSpawn> playerSpawn;
}

[Serializable]
public class PlayerSpawn
{
    public string PlayerName;
    public float posx;
    public float posz;
}
```